# Ignore color output from within the shader

Tags: opengl, glsl

Is it possible from within the shader to ignore colour output all together for a particular FBO color attachment?

Something like this for example:

```
#version 330

layout (location = 0) out vec4 output_A;    
layout (location = 1) out vec4 output_B;

uniform float isGlass;

void main(void)
{
    if (isGlass = 0)
    {
        output_A = vec4(1,1,1,1);
        output_B = vec4(1,1,1,1);
    }
    else
    {
        output_A = vec4(1,1,1,1);
        output_B = NULL;
    }   
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, this is not possible from inside a shader.

But you can achieve a similar effect by enabling alpha-blending ([`glBlendFunci`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glBlendFunc.xhtml)) for the second renderbuffer and set the alpha channel to 0 when nothing should be written.

Edit:

The shader could under the assumption that the blending mode for the second render target is set to `(GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA)` look like this:

```
#version 330

layout (location = 0) out vec4 output_A;    
layout (location = 1) out vec4 output_B;

uniform float isGlass;

void main(void)
{
    if (isGlass = 0)
    {
        output_A = vec4(1,1,1,1);
        output_B = vec4(1,1,1,1);
    }
    else
    {
        output_A = vec4(1,1,1,1);
        output_B = vec4(0,0,0,0); //Will not be written since alpha = 0
    }   
}
```

Comment: Interesting, so you can enable/disable alpha blending for individual color attachments?

Comment: Yes. That's what `glBlendFunci` is there for.

Comment: I'm struggling to get this working, if you have a moment could you post an example shader? The goal is to write no output depending on the outcome of an if statement.

Comment: Thank you. I'd written `glDisable` accidentally. At least the answer is super explicit now.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to turn off writes to a particular attachment, this is best done through [write masking](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Write_Mask#Color_Mask). Color masks can be enabled/disabled on a per-attachment basis with `glColorMaski`:

```
glColorMask(buffer, GL_FALSE, GL_FALSE, GL_FALSE, GL_FALSE);
```

`buffer` is the location that the output variable is associated with.

Of course, this can only be done between draw calls. But since you're using a `uniform` to control this, it shouldn't be a problem.